# Implement debounce to Vuetify data table custom filter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, debouncing

I want to implement a debounce method so that the search does not happen again at every keystroke. With the way I've implemented, the search still happens at every keystroke instead of waiting for 1 second after last keystroke. What else can I do?

Template:

```
  <v-data-table
        :pagination.sync="pagination"
        :rows-per-page-items="[10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 250, 500]"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="rows"
        select-all
        :search="search"
        :custom-filter="_debounce(searchFilter, 1000)"
        v-model="selected"
      >
```

Method in vue file's script:

```
_debounce(fn: Function, delay: number) {
  debounce(fn, delay)
},
```

The source function (defined in my own library):

```
export const debounce = function (fn: Function, delay: number) {
  var timeoutID: any = null
  return function () {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID)
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
      fn()
    }, delay)
  }
}
```

Comment: `custom-filter` prop expects a single function that will handle the filtering of items.  The function signature should be `(value: any, search: string | null, item: any)` and the expected return value is a boolean.  You have to write this function as this is what the prop was made for.  Debouncing can be added to it, but you still need to write it.  Your code is written as if the default filtering function (searchFilter) is provided and can be called like normal, but it's not

Comment: What do you mean by imported debounce method?

Comment: In order to use this same logic across many places in the app, in my own library, I define and export a function called debounce. I then import this function in the vue file, and use it in _debounce method.

Answer (score 0):

I use the custom-filter function along with lodash.debounce in my vuetify project.  I use customFilter as a way to search nested values by flattening when a column contains an Object.  I also use a computed get/set to contain the debounce

```js
// Looking for the v1.5 template?
// https://codepen.io/pen?template=GVoaNe


// import debounce from 'lodash.debounce'

const App = {
  template: '#app-template',
  data: () => ({
    headers: [
      { text: 'Name', value: 'name' },
      { text: 'Age', value: 'age' },
      { text: 'Occupation', value: 'occupation' },
      { text: 'Hire Date', value: 'hide_date' },
      { text: 'Favorite Foods', value: 'foods' }
    ],
    items: [
      { name: 'John', age: 21, occupation: 'Temp', hide_date: '2022-12-01', foods: [{ type: 'breakfast', food: 'Eggs' }, { type: 'lunch', food: 'Sandwich' }, { type: 'dinner', food: 'Steak' }] },
      { name: 'Jacob', age: 42, occupation: 'VP', hide_date: '2021-11-19', foods: [{ type: 'breakfast', food: 'Waffles' }, { type: 'lunch', food: 'Soup' }, { type: 'dinner', food: 'Sausage' }] },
      { name: 'Jingleheimer', age: 63, occupation: 'President', hide_date: '2020-06-07', foods: [{ type: 'breakfast', food: 'Pancakes' }, { type: 'lunch', food: 'Sandwich' }, { type: 'dinner', food: 'Salad' }]},
      { name: 'Schmidt', age: 84, occupation: 'CEO', hide_date: '2010-01-01', foods: [{ type: 'breakfast', food: 'Omelete' }, { type: 'lunch', food: 'Pizza' }, { type: 'dinner', food: 'Beans' }] },
      { name: 'asdfq', age: 88, occupation: 'CO-CEO', hide_date: '2010-01-02', foods: [{ type: 'breakfast', food: 'Fruit' }, { type: 'lunch', food: 'Torta' }, { type: 'dinner', food: 'Tuna' }] },
      { name: 'asdfqwerty', age: 99, occupation: 'Chairman', hide_date: '2009-12-31', foods: [{ type: 'breakfast', food: 'Coffee' }, { type: 'lunch', food: 'Burrito' }, { type: 'dinner', food: 'Bugs' }] }
    ],
    search_value: ''
  }),
  computed: {
    // I'm putting a debounce into a computed setter
    search: {
      get () { return this.search_value },
      set: debounce(function (value) {
        this.search_value = value 
      }, 300)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    /******************************
    * This custom filter function allows the filter to search nested properties by flattening nested values.
    * In this example data the `foods` column contains an array of objects to be flattened before doing a case-insensitive search
    ******************************/
    customFilter (value, search, item) {
      return Object
        .values(item)
        .flat()
        .map(x => { return (!!x && typeof x === 'object') ? Object.values(x) : x })
        .flat()
        .some(x => x && x.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
    }
  }
}


new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash.debounce@4.0.8/index.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items" :search="search" :custom-filter="customFilter">
        <template #[`item.foods`]="{ item }">
          <pre>{{ item.foods }}</pre>
        </template>
        <template #top>
          <!-- i'm NOT using v-model here, but the @input event is what calls `debounceInput`, which sets the value of `search` (debounced 250ms) -->
          <v-text-field
            v-model="search"
            label="Search"
            outlined
            prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
            clearable
          />
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

https://codepen.io/slybootz/pen/JjBdWGg?editors=1011